# AlarmManager does not fire PendingIntent - Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have made a class to set an AlarmManager and to receive it with a BroadcastReceiver, but it does not work. I tried already different types to set de AlarmManager, but nothing worked. Of course the BroadcastRecevier works fine if I call it in a other way.

```
public class AlarmBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if(intent==null)
        {
            Log.d("INFO", "Intent is null");
        }

        if(context==null)
        {
            Log.d("INFO", "Context is null");
        }

        if(intent!=null && context!=null)
        {
            Log.d("INFO", "AlarmManager fired...");
        }
    }

    public static void startAlarm(Context context)
    {
        if(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE)==null)
        {
            Log.d("INFO", "AlarmManager set...");
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 10000, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, new Intent(context, AlarmBroadcastReceiver.class), 0));
        }
    }
}
```

I hope you can help me! Thanks :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `RTC_WAKEUP`, but your time base is expressed as `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()`. Those do not match. Either use `ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP` or change your time for the event to be based off of `System.currentTimeMillis()` or things that use it (e.g., `java.util.Calendar`).

Beyond that, confirm that your `AlarmBroadcastReceiver` is registered in the manifest, and see if you have any LogCat messages related to your problem.

Comment: Thanks it worked after changing `SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()` into `System.currentTimeMillis()`